# What is the difference between `value` attribute and `ng-value` attributes in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service

What is the difference between `value` and `ng-value` attributes in angularjs templates? If I use `ng-if` on the field using value attribute it works properly but if I change the attribute `value` to `ng-value` it stops working.

```
example 1  // it works 

<input type='radio' ng-model='difficulty' value='hard'/>
<div ng-if="difficulty == 'hard'">
     <p>difficulty is hard</p>
</div>  

Example 2 // it doesn't work

<input type='radio' ng-model='level' ng-value='hard'/>
<div ng-if= "level == 'hard'" >
     <p>level is hard</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to **[the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue)**, `ngValue` takes an *"angular expression, whose value will be bound to the `value` attribute of the `input` element"*.

So, when you use `ng-value="hard"`, it is interpreted as an expression and the `value` is bound to `$scope.hard` (which is probably `undefined`).
`ngValue` is useful for evaluating expressions - it has no advantage over `value` for setting hard-coded values. Yet, if you want to hard-code a value with `ngValue`, you must enclose it in `''`:

```
ng-value="'hard'"
```

---

**UPDATE:**
Starting with v1.6, `ngValue` will also set the `value` **property** of the element (in addition to the `value` attribute). It might not affect your usecase, but it's another difference worth keeping in mind.

Comment: Okay, means when i type `ng-value='hard'` it will search `$scope.hard` but when i type `value='hard' it will assign the value 'hard' to that field. thank you

Comment: How about `ng-value=false`? In this case, it is interpreted as string `false` instead of `scope.false`.

Comment: It is interpreted as boolean false and converted to string when assigning to the attribute `value`. It depends on how Angular's parser works.

Comment: @ExpertSystem so how would `ng-value="someExpression"` be different from the simpler: `value={{someExpression}}` ?

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus: Most of the time it won't (there are some very subtle differences, which are really out of scope here). But then again, I would argue that `ng-value="someExpr"` is simpler than `value="{{ someExpr }}"`. Basically, I would use `ngValue` whenever I have an expression to evaluate and `value` when the value is constant.

Comment: @ExpertSystem , here is the difference which I found: adding an `<option>` with `ng-value` attribute will not work well if we intend to change the text in of the tag. Here is a plunker for demo: [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/d8NUzYWHYrNTgEE8bx5K)
if you change ln#17 with html in ln#18 then it will work correctly. (the code was supposed to change the text of the html option from "All Venues" to "Reset Venues" and back)

Comment: @Tamas, both versions work for me. Note that this is a pretty old answer so things might change.