# Get value from getElementById in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, getelementbyid

View

```
    <button  class="ion-ios-close-outline" ng-click="change()"></button> 

           <label  class="item item-input">  
                <input  id='test' type="text"  ng-value="77"/> 
            </label>
```

Controller

```
 $scope.change = function () {  
            var x=angular.element(document.getElementById("test"));                
            alert(x.value);

        };
```

The output is `undefined`.
What am i doing wrong in here?
Please help.

Comment: Check out this post, it should clear things up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865608/what-is-the-difference-between-value-attribute-and-ng-value-attributes-in-an

Comment: I have provided the alternative to ngModel as you have asked.

Comment: `x.val()` still gave me `undefined`,please help

Comment: if you want to modify the value, maybe you could do a Directive, you can acces the element inside , and if you want to do for multiple inputs just add the directive, or with a filter would be possible too

Comment: It should be working. I created sample Code pen for same:

[Sample code](http://codepen.io/Diljohn5741/pen/jWGZrE)

Comment: @Diljohn5741 I tried it,but cannot get it working.

Comment: @oxigenao what if it's inside a foreach loop?

Comment: I created exact replica of your code. So hard to understand the issue.
Are you able to see value inside textbox in browser? i.e. ngmodel is setting up value to text box?

Comment: @Diljohn5741 Thank you..It works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular.element returns wrapper of jQlite. It's similar to jquery. So it doesn't support value.

Either use

```
x.val()
```

or

```
x[0].value
```

Either way i would recommend not to use such type of changes in controller. It should be done only in directives.
You should use model of input box to access such values in controllers.

Comment: This is inside a foreach loop so i cannot use model

Comment: It's up to you. You can use the mentioned alternative.

Comment: alerting `x.val()` still gave me `undefined` please help

Comment: Can you check this code pen i created.
[code pen](http://codepen.io/Diljohn5741/pen/jWGZrE)

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-model on your input;

set ng-model='test'

```
<input  id='test' type="text" ng-model='test' ng-value="77"/>
```

and on the change function set

```
var x=$scope.test;
        alert(x);
```

Edited

```
var a = angular.element(document.getElementById('t'));
var attr = a[0].attributes;
var value = attr.getNamedItem("ng-value");

console.log(value.value);
```

Comment: I know this but I need to use `getElementById`  and get the result

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your solution is bad.
Angular API allow to use data binding.
So you should use ng-model in you input compoment for example:

```
<button  class="ion-ios-close-outline" ng-click="change()"></button> 
<label  class="item item-input">  
    <input  id='test' type="text" ng-model="test"/>
```

```
$scope.test = 77;
$scope.change = function () {  
    alert($scope.test);
};
```

Comment: The entire thing is inside a foreach loop so i need Id for identifying each element ,do i have a choice?

Comment: So you should use list of variable. Show your code that'll help you

Comment: Thanks bro, I got the solution.