# Set initial value of text input field without triggering ng-change

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays

The scenario is a Sudoku game with JavaScript and AngularJS.

The Sudoku field is an Array (rows) of Arrays (columns). All arrays have a length of 9. I name this Sudoku field `matrix`. The function `exampleMatrix()` returns such a matrix which already has some fields filled.

An `updateValue(sudokuMatrix, row, col, val)` function changes the field at position row `row` and column `col` in the matrix `sudokuMatrix` to the value `val`.

```
function TestController($scope) {
    $scope.matrix = exampleMatrix();
    $scope.updateValue = updateValue;
    $scope.getMatrixVal = function getMatrixVal(row, col) {
        return $scope.matrix[row][col];
    };
}
```

What I want to do is to display every field of the matrix as an `<input type="text">` field in HTML. I want all the fields to be initially set to the values they have in the matrix. If the input of a text field is changed, I want the value to be updated in the `$scope.matrix` object.

I can fill the fields with the values of the matrix with no problem with the following HTML/AngularJS Code:

```
<div ng-repeat="(rowIndex,row) in matrix track by $index">
    <input type="text" size="1" value="{{col}}"
           ng-repeat="(colIndex,col) in row track by $index">
</div>
```

But I cannot update the values in the `$scope.matrix` object yet, of course.

The problems I am facing are

1. If I change the value in an input field, the `matrix` should update that value. I can do this with `ng-change="updateValue(matrix, rowIndex, colIndex, inputVal)"`.
2. In order to be able to change the `matrix` in the scope with `ng-change`, I need an `ng-model`, which binds the input of the field to a variable: `ng-model="inputVal"`
3. If I add those two lines, the input fields are not filled initally with the values in the `matrix` object of the scope.

The current code looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(rowIndex,row) in matrix track by $index">
    <input type="text" size="1" value="{{getMatrixVal(rowIndex, colIndex)}}"
           ng-model="inputVal"
           ng-change="updateValue(matrix, rowIndex, colIndex, inputVal)"
           ng-repeat="(colIndex,col) in row track by $index">
</div>
```

My guess is that when the site is generated, `ng-model` assigns the empty value of the input field to `inputVal`, and that `ng-change` is immediately triggered. Every field of the matrix would thus be populated with an empty value. AngularJS is not throwing any errors though, so I cannot be sure. Anyways, I'm at a loss here and do not know how to get the initial values to be written to the fields initially and `ng-change` to be only called afterwards. I appreciate every help.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/30xkedmp/

JavaScript: http://pastebin.com/8cge8BXs
HTML: http://pastebin.com/X0YUPU4h

Comment: would it be possible to share a url where you have deployed your code so that it will be easy to test?

Comment: Appended the links to the code at the end of the post. I haven't deployed it online though, sorry.

Comment: create fiddle, it will be easy for us. https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Finally got the fiddle to work. Appended the link at the end of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use

```
<div ng-repeat="(rowIndex,row) in matrix track by $index">
    <input type="text" size="1" ng-model="matrix[rowIndex][colIndex]"
           ng-repeat="(colIndex,col) in row track by $index">
</div>
```

instead of

```
<div ng-repeat="(rowIndex,row) in matrix track by $index">
    <input type="text" size="1" value="{{getMatrixVal(rowIndex, colIndex)}}"
           ng-model="inputVal"
           ng-change="updateValue(matrix, rowIndex, colIndex, inputVal)"
           ng-repeat="(colIndex,col) in row track by $index">
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't think of it, makes it cleaner. But I still have the problem that the values I write into the input fields won't update the matrix in the Controller.

Comment: ng-model is two way binding, so it updates values in controller when you change your view and updates your view when you change your controllers values

Comment: You were indeed right, sorry. I ran into problems with my code because I parsed the input String to an int with my `updateValue(...)` method, which I can't do that easily now with ng-model. The way I checked for changes did not recognize the Strings and it seemed to me that the value did not get registered. Anyways, you're absolutely right and this code is way simpler than the other option (and your answer was the first one), so I changed my vote.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code and see,I have only replaced your value attribute with the ng-value attribute in input tag as shown below,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="TestController">
<div ng-repeat="(rowIndex,row) in matrix track by $index">
  <input type="text" size="1" ng-value="getMatrixVal(rowIndex, colIndex)"
         ng-model="inputVal"
         ng-change="updateValue(matrix, rowIndex, colIndex, inputVal)"
         ng-repeat="(colIndex,col) in row track by $index">
</div>
<script>
angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('app').config(['$controllerProvider', function($controllerProvider) {
  $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
}]);

function emptyRow() {
  return [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
}

function emptyMatrix() {
  var sudokuMatrix = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    sudokuMatrix[i] = emptyRow();
  }
  return sudokuMatrix;
}

function updateValue(sudokuMatrix, row, col, val) {
  row = parseInt(row);
  col = parseInt(col);
  val = parseInt(val);
  sudokuMatrix[row][col] = val;
}

function exampleMatrix() {
  matrix = emptyMatrix();
  updateValue(matrix, 0, 2, 6);
  updateValue(matrix, 0, 3, 3);
  updateValue(matrix, 0, 4, 2);

  updateValue(matrix, 1, 2, 1);
  updateValue(matrix, 1, 5, 5);
  updateValue(matrix, 1, 6, 3);
  updateValue(matrix, 1, 7, 6);

  updateValue(matrix, 2, 0, 9);
  updateValue(matrix, 2, 1, 4);
  updateValue(matrix, 2, 3, 6);

  updateValue(matrix, 3, 2, 4);

  updateValue(matrix, 4, 0, 8);
  updateValue(matrix, 4, 1, 7);
  updateValue(matrix, 4, 3, 1);
  updateValue(matrix, 4, 4, 3);
  updateValue(matrix, 4, 5, 4);
  updateValue(matrix, 4, 7, 5);
  updateValue(matrix, 4, 8, 6);

  updateValue(matrix, 5, 6, 1);

  updateValue(matrix, 6, 5, 9);
  updateValue(matrix, 6, 7, 4);
  updateValue(matrix, 6, 8, 7);

  updateValue(matrix, 7, 1, 1);
  updateValue(matrix, 7, 2, 7);
  updateValue(matrix, 7, 3, 5);
  updateValue(matrix, 7, 6, 2);

  updateValue(matrix, 8, 4, 7);
  updateValue(matrix, 8, 5, 2);
  updateValue(matrix, 8, 6, 5);

  return matrix;
}

function TestController($scope) {
  $scope.matrix = exampleMatrix();
  $scope.updateValue = updateValue;
  $scope.getMatrixVal = function(row, col) {
    return $scope.matrix[row][col];
  };
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code snippet won't function here because it doesn't seem to be accepting the version of angular js i have specified, but the rest of the code is functioning well.

You can try replacing the value attribute by the ng-value attribute in your fiddle and try

Comment: I should have known that there must be a directive for it. That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! For anyone stumbling upon the same problem, there's more information in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865608/what-is-the-difference-between-value-attribute-and-ng-value-attributes-in-an

Comment: indeed, ng-value can be used instead of ng-model in your case, but you used here too much code, what you need is just single ng-model, without need to use ng-change, getMatrixVal function or "inpuVal" variable. Just as i mentioned in comment below my answer - ng-model directive is two way binding, so it updates controllers variables automatically ; ) 
take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717523/whats-the-difference-between-ng-model-and-ng-value