# AngularJS Hide/Show questions based on Radio answers in ng-repeat block

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am learning angular by doing, so please excuse me if this is a basic question. I want to hide questions based on the previous questions answers.  For instance Q1 appears first, if the user selects answer11 and Q2 appears.  If the user selects answer12 Q2 doesn't appear.  I also want to make sure that the radio button are cleared. Essentially creating a workflow.  From previous questions I had putting in the model might be a solution when wanting to hide questions.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);


app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {


    $scope.questions = [{
        questiontxt: 'Please select your Age range',
        qid: 1234,
        Answer: [{
          answertxt: "answer11",
          aId: 83493,
           removes: [{
              qid: 5678,
              }]
        }, {
          answertxt: "answer12",
          aId: 1223
        }]
      },
      {
        questiontxt: 'Please select your favorite activity',
        qid: 5678,
        Answer: [{
          answertxt: "answer21",
          aId: 90886
        }, {
          answertxt: "answer22",
          aId: 67107
        }]
      },
      {
        questiontxt: 'Please select your favorite food',
        qid: 4321,
        Answer: [{
          answertxt: "answer31",
          aId: 32342
        }, {
          answertxt: "answer32",
          aId: 79130
        }]
      }
    ];
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.14"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="question in questions">
    <div class="row">
      <br/><span>Q{{$index+1}}. {{question.questiontxt}}</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="answer in question.Answer">
      <input type="radio" value="{{answer.answertxt}}{{$parent.$index}}" ng-model="question.selectedAnswer" ng-value="{{answer.answertxt}}" />{{answer.answertxt}}
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**Update**

I am updating the question because I wasn't clear.  If the user selects answer11 in Q1 then Q2 appears. If the user selects answer12 then Q2 disappears but Q3 is still visible.  The only way Q2 appears is when the user selects answer11. I am trying to create dependencies between questions based on what is put into the model.

Answer (score 0):

Just make an iterator, and increment every time you answer a question - like so:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);


app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.questionNo = 0;

    $scope.questions = [{
        questiontxt: 'Please select your Age range',
        qid: 1234,
        Answer: [{
          answertxt: "answer11",
          aId: 83493,
           removes: [{
              qid: 4321,
              }]
        }, {
          answertxt: "answer12",
          aId: 1223
        }]
      },
      {
        questiontxt: 'Please select your favorite activity',
        qid: 5678,
        Answer: [{
          answertxt: "answer21",
          aId: 90886
        }, {
          answertxt: "answer22",
          aId: 67107
        }]
      },
      {
        questiontxt: 'Please select your favorite food',
        qid: 4321,
        Answer: [{
          answertxt: "answer31",
          aId: 32342
        }, {
          answertxt: "answer32",
          aId: 79130
        }]
      }
    ];

    $scope.incrementQuestionNo = function() {
        if ($scope.questionNo != $scope.questions.length-1)
        {
            $scope.questionNo++;
        }
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.14"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <br/><span>Q{{questionNo+1}}. {{questions[questionNo].questiontxt}}</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="answer in questions[questionNo].Answer">
      <input type="radio" ng-model="questions[questionNo].selectedAnswer" ng-change="incrementQuestionNo()" ng-value="{{answer.answertxt}}" />{{answer.answertxt}}
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Btw, ng-value and value are mutally exclusive. Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865608/what-is-the-difference-between-value-attribute-and-ng-value-attributes-in-an).

Answer (score 0):

add a property to the questions array with a bool value to show/hide. And use ng-change to update it accordingly.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);


app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

    $scope.questions = [{
        questiontxt: 'Please select your Age range',
        qid: 1234,
        show: true,
        Answer: [{
          answertxt: "answer11",
          aId: 83493,
           removes: [{
              qid: 4321,
              }]
        }, {
          answertxt: "answer12",
          aId: 1223
        }]
      },
      {
        questiontxt: 'Please select your favorite activity',
        qid: 5678,
        show: false,
        Answer: [{
          answertxt: "answer21",
          aId: 90886
        }, {
          answertxt: "answer22",
          aId: 67107
        }]
      },
      {
        questiontxt: 'Please select your favorite food',
        qid: 4321,
        show: false,
        Answer: [{
          answertxt: "answer31",
          aId: 32342
        }, {
          answertxt: "answer32",
          aId: 79130
        }]
      }
    ];

   $scope.updateQuestions = function(index){
        // you write the rest
        // use the index to get the current question
        // get the selected answer
        // set the next question's show to true or false

        // for example (not a solution)
        if(index === 0){
           $scope.questions[1].show = true;
        }
   }
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.14"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="question in questions track by $index">
    <div ng-if="question.show">
    <div class="row">
      <br/><span>Q{{$index+1}}. {{question.questiontxt}}</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="answer in question.Answer">
      <input type="radio" value="{{answer.answertxt}}{{$parent.$index}}" ng-model="question.selectedAnswer" ng-value="{{answer.answertxt}}" ng-change="updateQuestions($index)" />{{answer.answertxt}}
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```